# AWS push notification in other lanuguages

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification

Am working on Android webview,I am receiving push notification from Amazon web service SNS service in English but I want the push notification in other languages like tamil, Hindi, etc.

Comment: What is the content of the push? Is it just a code specifying what text is to be shown in notification? Or is it the complete text?
If it's code then you can localize the content inside Android app. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: content of push is simple text, If I push tamil text from aws service,Am getting junk value.

Comment: Would you please post your code? I suspect you don't encode string with UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: I used UTF-8 that solved my issue thanks @yangfan